# Overloading global functions in helpers

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

I'm adding some functions for `TPoint` and if I use the same name as the global function, I can't see it inside helper function. Am I missing something or I can't simply do that?

```
uses 
  Winapi.Windows, Math;

type
  TPointHelper = record helper for TPoint
    function InRange(const AMin, AMax: TPoint): Boolean;
  end;

implementation

function TPointHelper.InRange(const AMin, AMax: TPoint): Boolean;
begin
  Result := InRange(X, AMin.X, AMax.X) and InRange(Y, AMin.Y, AMax.Y);
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fully qualify the call to `InRange` because the compiler sees the `InRange` in the closest scope. Which is your helper method. Your code should read:

```
function TPointHelper.InRange(const AMin, AMax: TPoint): Boolean;
begin
  Result := Math.InRange(X, AMin.X, AMax.X) and Math.InRange(Y, AMin.Y, AMax.Y);
end;
```

Comment: Is there any possibility how to use overloaded function of `InRange` inside the same unit?

Comment: You can do it the same way, using the unit name to fully qualify the name

Comment: Thanks it works. I really thought, that when the function is in the same unit, I don't need to fully qualify the name.

Comment: You wouldn't normally, unless you take it out of scope with a method